# How to use socket.io in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I learn node and I have example with socket.io.

In package.json I have:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "test",
  "dependencies": {
    "mime": "~1.2.7",
    "socket.io": "*"
  }
}
```

And I do:

```
npm install
```

I receive:

```
+-- mime@1.2.11
`-- socket.io@1.7.3
  +-- debug@2.3.3
  | `-- ms@0.7.2
  +-- engine.io@1.8.3
  | +-- accepts@1.3.3
  | | +-- mime-types@2.1.14
  | | | `-- mime-db@1.26.0
  | | `-- negotiator@0.6.1
  | +-- base64id@1.0.0
  | +-- cookie@0.3.1
  | +-- engine.io-parser@1.3.2
  | | +-- after@0.8.2
  | | +-- arraybuffer.slice@0.0.6
  | | +-- base64-arraybuffer@0.1.5
  | | +-- blob@0.0.4
  | | `-- wtf-8@1.0.0
  | `-- ws@1.1.2
  |   +-- options@0.0.6
  |   `-- ultron@1.0.2
  +-- has-binary@0.1.7
  | `-- isarray@0.0.1
  +-- object-assign@4.1.0
  +-- socket.io-adapter@0.5.0
  +-- socket.io-client@1.7.3
  | +-- backo2@1.0.2
  | +-- component-bind@1.0.0
  | +-- component-emitter@1.2.1
  | +-- engine.io-client@1.8.3
  | | +-- component-emitter@1.2.1
  | | +-- component-inherit@0.0.3
  | | +-- has-cors@1.1.0
  | | +-- parsejson@0.0.3
  | | +-- parseqs@0.0.5
  | | +-- xmlhttprequest-ssl@1.5.3
  | | `-- yeast@0.1.2
  | +-- indexof@0.0.1
  | +-- object-component@0.0.3
  | +-- parseuri@0.0.5
  | | `-- better-assert@1.0.2
  | |   `-- callsite@1.0.0
  | `-- to-array@0.1.4
  `-- socket.io-parser@2.3.1
    +-- component-emitter@1.1.2
    +-- debug@2.2.0
    | `-- ms@0.7.1
    `-- json3@3.3.2
```

**So no error.**

In html I use (as in example):

```
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

But in console I have error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"
```

In folder **node_modules** I have structure:

```
node_modules
--- socket.io
------ lib
--------- client.js
--------- index.js
--------- namespace.js
--------- socket.js
```

I tried also others path:

/socket.io/lib/socket.js
/socket.io/socket.js

/socket.io/lib/index.js
/socket.io/index.js

etc... but still I have error 404. How can I include this to my project in html?

Comment: where do you install the node package? it should <node_package_dir>/<socket_io> .

Comment: You need to show us your server-side code for initializing and configuring socket.io.  If that is done correctly, then `/socket.io/socket.io.js` will work when the client requests it.  But, we need to see your server-side code in order to point out what you're missing.

Answer (score -1):

You need to

```
npm install --save-dev socket.io-client
```

And use

```
<script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Or, if you use CommonJS or ES6 on client, you can import scoket.io by

```
const io = require('socket.io-client')
```

or

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
```

Comment: This is not needed if socket.io is properly installed on the server as a properly installed socket.io server will automatically serve `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.